# Problem in removing special characters from a string through js

Tags: javascript

I am using this function to remove anything other than numbers, but it is giving me error, value.replace in not a function, Here's the function :

```
function filter_value(value)
{
    var filter = value.replace(/[^0-9.]+/g,''); 
    return filter;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function filter_value(value) {
    return parseInt(value.toString().replace(/\D+/g,''), 10);
}
```

This will return integer value

Comment: It is not working, for example if i pass the digit 1,002, it makes it 1 & skip 002, Please help

Answer (score 2):

If `replace` is not a function then `value` is not a string. Make sure you pass a string to the function.

Comment: +1, I'd also like to add: Try `value.toString().replace(/[^0-9.]+/g,'');` to make the function a bit more robust and accept numbers and objects and such.

Comment: I am passing a number with comma, and i want to remove the comma, so that i can do the calculation with that number.